# How can i get background colour decimals?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to read background color which i set in decimals e.g rgb(44.9, 19.373737, 255)
using this code

```
$("p").css("background-color")
```

but when used it keeps rounding it into rgb(45, 19, 255)

all i want to achieve is to get it in decimals

This is the sample code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        alert("Background color = " + $("p").css("background-color"));
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p style="background-color:rgb(44.9, 19.373737, 255)">This is a paragraph.</p>


<button>Return background-color of p</button>
```

Comment: thats what happens in background, rgb takes 3 integer values

Comment: Your `rgb()` shouldn't contain floating point numbers in the first place. This is not allowed. You should probably fix the code that generates this html output.

Comment: Where ever you set those values to the CSS, they are automatically either truncated or rounded to integers. You've to store the original decimals to a variable, if you need the decimals afterwards. Or, with native JS, [get the value of the style attribute](https://jsfiddle.net/fxLve6y9/): `element.attributes.style.value`, and extract the originally written value from the result. Looks like `$('p').attr('style')` will do too.

Comment: It's not possible to pass decimal values in RGB.

Comment: @sam It is possible, though the decimals are naturally ignored by browsers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fan of testing.

Let's pretend we don't know colours are made of integers and let's test:

Let's make 4 divs, one with your decimal values and 3 with red and green rounded up or down.

Next let's verify the output using a photo app like photofilter

https://jsfiddle.net/vgrtky7g/

The first div don't show in jsfiddle, don't show in chrome but shows in firefox and edge which is a good enough warning.

If you run the code in firefox you will get :

`#2D13FF` for both `rgb(44.9, 19.373737, 255)` and `rgb(45, 19, 255)` which means firefox was nice enough to round to the nearer integer.

Don't rely on browser kindness and use integers !

Answer (score 1):

RGB values are composed of three 8-bit integers (byte), for red, green and blue respectively ranges from 0 to 255. There are no fractional part allowed in those values. Hence your style is not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        alert("Background color = " + $("p").css("background-color"));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p style="background-color:rgb(44, 19, 255)">This is a paragraph.</p>


<button>Return background-color of p</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`rgb()` uses 8 bit color and 2^8 = 256. Therefore, you can only use **integers** ranging from `0` to `255`.

The issue seems to be with your backend logic which is generating decimal point values. You can round off the values before storing or using it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the decimal values make any sense. rather round of it and use it in RGB.